# Does the join order matter in the 'ON clause' in a LEFT JOIN in SQL?

Tags: sql

I would like to know if these two SQL queries give us the same result since the 'ON clause' is different.

```
-- A    
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id=b.id

-- B
SELECT * FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON b.id=a.id
```

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't matter how `ON` clause you wrote.

Comment: `5=5` does it matter which `5` is on which side of the operator?

Comment: Both sides are equally important to process the ON as it needs both the operands to process the "=" operator.

Answer (score 3):

No, the `JOIN` order does not matter.  SQL is a *descriptive* language, where a SQL query describes the result set, not how it is processed.  The compiler and optimizer figure out the execution plan.

The two conditions express the same condition.  However, the order of the *tables* in the `FROM` clause matters a great deal for an outer join.

I should note that SQL optimizers do not catch everything, so sometimes how something is expressed can affect the execution plan.  This wold not be such a case.